# Custom Post type permalink structure with custom_post_id

Tags: urls, permalinks

## THE QUESTION

Hello!

Currently, my permalink settings are set to *"Post Name"* so that the default wordpress posts which are used for articles will have a pretty urls.

But then, I have this job post (custom post type as "thjb_job") that needs to have these kinds for permalink structures:

For viewing a single job post

1.) **(rootURI) / job-post / %job_id%**

and for listing based on employers (employer as a kind of taxonomy)

2.) **(rootURI) / %taxonomy% / job-post / %job_id%**

My priority is the item no. 1 as I haven't added the employer taxonomy yet.

I have already used wordpress methods like
add_rewrite_tag() and add_permastruct() but they seems to not work properly.

I have also tried using add_filter('post_type_link') wordpress hook but it seems to just manipulate the permalink string record as it returns 404 when I tried to view the post (by clicking on the permalink while editing the custom post thjb_job).

Also, I have read a lot of answers that involves modification of .htaccess. I'm hoping that I won't need to touch .htaccess just to achieve this custom permalink structure.

**Thanks in advance for your help on how to achieve the permalink structures above.**

---

## THE CODES

Here are the ways I'm using the methods mentioned above

```
/**
 * AddCustomPostJob = Add Custom Post labeled as Job
 *   : this class registers a new custom post type called thjb_job (Job)
 */
class AddCustomPostJob {

/**
 * init() = Initializer Method
 *   : this method is the class engine starter
 *
 */
public static function init() {

    // Register the custom post type
    add_action( 'init', array(get_called_class(), 'registerPostType') );

    // Register custom rewrite rules for this custom post type
    add_action( 'init', array(get_called_class(), 'rewriteRules') );

    // Register custom url tag translations
    add_filter( 'post_type_link', array(get_called_class(), 'translateTags'), 10, 2 );

}



/**
 * registerPostType = Register Post Type callback
 *   : this method defines the properties for the custom post type
 */
public static function registerPostType() {

    // Define custom type child options

    // Labels
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Jobs' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Job' )
    );

    // Default fields
    $supports = array( 'title', 'editor' );

    // Turn off wordpress permalink rewrite
    $rewrite = false;

    // Define the options for the custom post type
    $opts = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'public'              => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'supports'            => $supports,
        'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
    );

    // Register the post type with key => thjb_job
    register_post_type( 'thjb_job', $opts);

} // registerPostType()



/**
 * rewriteRules() = Custom rewrite rules method
 *   : this method creates a custom rewrite rules exclusively for thjb_job post type
 *
 */
public static function rewriteRules() {

    // Define the custom permalink structure
    $structure = '/job-post/%job_id%';

    // Map the equivalent query var
    add_rewrite_tag("%job_id%", '([^/]+)', "p=");

    // Add the custom permalink structure to wordpess
    add_permastruct('thjb_job', $structure, false);
}




/**
 * translateTags() = Translate url tags method
 *   : this method translates tags (%tags%) to its original value
 *
 * @param $url
 *   : this param is the current url to be modified
 *
 * @param $post
 *   : this param is the current post being processed
 *
 * @return modified $url
 *
 */
public static function translateTags($url, $post) {

    // Apply only for thjb_job post type
    if ( $post->post_type == 'thjb_job') {

        // If %job_id% exists, then insert the original value
        if ( strpos($url, '%job_id%') ) {

            return str_replace('%job_id%', $post->ID, $url);
        }
    }

    return $url;

}


} // AddCustomPostJob class

AddCustomPostJob::init();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## THE ANSWER

First of all, this link helped me a lot

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/building-customized-urls-wordpress

It turned out the I don't need to use add_rewrite_tag(), but to use add_rewrite_rule() to achieve my goal.

**I wondered why --**

***%job_id%*** (or even ***%post_id%***, tried them both)

is not recognized in my permalink structure. I was expecting that ***%job_id%*** will be replaced by my custom_post's id as it is the tag I used for add_rewrite_tag(), pointing to "p" query var.

And only ***%postname%*** is being recognized correctly.

**Then, I removed the callback for add_filter('post_type_link')**

**Result :** When I save the new post, the permalink is becoming as is "job-post/%job_id%", %job_id% not being a variable but a hardcoded string.

**Then I turned off everything**

**Result :** I discovered that the original query URL turned out to be:

**www.mysite.com/?thjb_job=THE_NAME_OF_THE_JOB_POST_ITEM**

Which I assume is the reason behind why "p" query var is not recognized, because only the postname is provided.

**So I turned everything back on again, and modified the rewriteRules() method**

Here is the modification as compared to THE CODES above :

```
/**
 * rewriteRules() = Custom rewrite rules method
 *   : this method creates a custom rewrite rules exclusively for thjb_job post type
 *
 */
public static function rewriteRules() {

    // Define the custom permalink structure
    $structure = '/job-post/%job_id%';

    // Add the custom permalink structure to wordpess
    add_permastruct('thjb_job', $structure, false);

    // Define the original query url that should be executed to grab the post
    $query = 'index.php?post_type=thjb_job&p=$matches[1]';

    // Apply the query to be called when user bumps into this url pattern
    add_rewrite_rule('^job-post/([^/]+)', $query, 'top');

}
```